# reading input from user within a given time, otherwise exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am working on a script where the user should provide his/her input within 20 seconds. If it's not provided within that time, then the script should exit

```
countdown()
(
  # https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-display-countdown-timer-in-bash-shell-script-running-on-linuxunix/  
  IFS=:
  set -- $*
  secs=$(( ${1#0} * 3600 + ${2#0} * 60 + ${3#0} ))
  while [ $secs -gt 0 ]
  do
    sleep 1 &
    printf "\r%02d:%02d:%02d" $((secs/3600)) $(( (secs/60)%60)) $((secs%60))
    secs=$(( $secs - 1 ))
    wait
  done
  echo
  

)

echo -n "Your answer : countdown "00:00:20" ";  read readUserInput
```

Comment: So `read -t 20 input` no?

Comment: @KamilCuk   can you share the code how to add that with an sample example taking value from user

Comment: 1. Remove all code. 2. Do `if ! read -t 20 readUserInput; then exit; fi`.

Comment: @KamilCuk  not working echo "Read input from user : "
read readUserInput

if ! read -t 20 readUserInput; then exit; fi

Comment: @KamilCuk  is it possible to show the count down time like 20 19 18 17 ....once 20 seconds over popup with msg your count down over and exit

Comment: `not working` is very vague. What exactly and how is it "not working"? `read readUserInput if ! read ` - you are `read`ing twice. Remove the first read. `over popup` I do not know what a "popup" would be. To do anything complicated, write a program using a real programming language and potentially use a terminal controlling library, like `ncurses`. To display incrementing numbers, I would do that in a background process and just terminate that process once read is completed. Note about [followup questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/9072753).

Comment: @KamilCuk can you provide your input i made some changes in question code

Comment: Please - for asking a followup questions ask another question. Please do not create chameleon questions - you asked how to timeout a read for 20 seconds, now you seem ask how to display a timer - that's a _different_ question. Please take your time to study shell language. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). In the spirit of this forum - ask a question, ending with a question mark, in your post.

Answer (score 0):

> where the user should provide his/her input within 20 seconds , if its not provided then the script should exit

So timeout the read after 20 seconds.

```
# the user should provide his/her input within 20 seconds
if ! read -r -t 20 input; then
     # if its not provided then the script should exit
     exit
fi
```

Note that `-t` option to `read` is a `bash` extension to posix shell. On posix compatible shell, I think I would go with `timeout` command and a subshell reading from user, something along `input=$(timeout 20 sh -c 'read -r input && printf "%s\n" "$input"')`.

> [Imaginary question OP never asked]: How to ask user for input with a 20 seconds timeout and at the same time provide a timer counting from 20 to 0?

Display a countdown in a background process. The following implementation uses SIGUSR1 to communicate with the background process that it's time to stop (well, using SIGTERM doesn't want to work well). Also it uses `\e[s` and `\e[u` ansi escape codes to restore cursor position after each inputted character to proper location. TLDR: looks like fun.

```
countdown() (
    # https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-display-countdown-timer-in-bash-shell-script-running-on-linuxunix/  
    local fmt=$1
    local secs=$(($2+1))
    trap exit SIGUSR1
    printf "$fmt" "$(printf "%02d:%02d:%02d" "$((secs / 3600))" "$(( (secs / 60) % 60))" "$((secs % 60))")"
    while ((secs--)); do
            sleep 1 &
            printf "\e[s\r$fmt\e[u" "$(printf "%02d:%02d:%02d" "$((secs / 3600))" "$(( (secs / 60) % 60))" "$((secs % 60))")"
            wait
    done
    printf "\r%fmt" "00:00:00"
)
countdown_end() {
    pkill -SIGUSR1 -P "$1" # sending SIGUSR1 hoping for gracefull exit
    wait "$1"
}

timeout=5
countdown "Countdown %s: input: " "$timeout" &
child=$!
if ! read -r -t "$timeout" readUserInput; then 
    countdown_end "$child"
    echo
    exit
fi
countdown_end "$child"
echo "You inputted " "$readUserInput"
```